# Creating a simple searchbox with filters

Tags: forms, scala, playframework-2.0

Edit: So I learned a lesson about checking string constants today. The solution was to change "filter" to "filters" in the template.

I'm trying to build a simple searchbox, with 4 checkboxes to apply some filters. Problem is that the checkboxes never return true, even when checked in dev mode.

I have defined my form like this, where `Filters` is a case class wrapper holding the 4 bools:

```
val searchBox = Form(
   tuple("search" -> nonEmptyText,
  "filters" -> mapping(
    "filterpublic" -> boolean,
    "filterprivate" -> boolean,
    "filterstream" -> boolean,
    "filterdownload" -> boolean
    ) (Filters.apply) (Filters.unapply)
)
```

)

My html-template is defined like so:

```
@form(action = routes.Application.getResults, 'id -> "searchBox") {

  <fieldset>
  <legend>Searchbox</legend>
    @inputText(field = searchBox("search"), args = '_label -> "search",
      'placeholder -> "Type here!")

    @checkbox(field = searchBox("filter.filterpublic"), args =
 '_label -> None, '_text -> "public")

@checkbox(field = searchBox("filter.filterprivate"), args =
 '_label -> None, '_text -> "private")

    @checkbox(field = searchBox("filter.filterstream"), args =
 '_label -> None, '_text -> "streamable")

@checkbox(field = searchBox("filter.filterdownload"), args =
 '_label -> None, '_text -> "downloadable")

  <input type="submit" id="submit">
  </fieldset>
}
```

I'm completely stumped as to what this could stem from. I have consulted the tutorials on the play! website, but could not find anything that addressed this specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change 'filter' to 'filters' in your template too. So 'filters.filterpublic' instead of 'filter.filterpublic'.